# Does elisp have regexp literals?

Tags: elisp, regular-expressions, syntax

The sheer number of backslashes my regexps require is pretty crazy. Does elisp have regexp literals, so I can write something like

```
rx"some\(regexp\)"
```

instead of

```
"some\\(regexp\\)"
```

Comment: Emacs highlights some regexp constructs like `\\|`, `\\(`, and `\\)`. Unfortunately, in many themes this isn't visible. You can override `font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash` and `font-lock-regexp-grouping-construct` to make this more distinct.

Comment: I've made a [patch](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/152132) to support raw string literals but the devs are not interested.

Comment: You can always tweak how things are displayed, as in this blog post by @abo-abo: http://oremacs.com/2015/01/11/pretty-elisp-regex/

Comment: @knarf it's a shame that Stefan wasn't interested in raw string support, because raw strings would be a complement for a new regexp syntax (which I would be in favor of), not a replacement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to use the `rx` macro to construct your expressions using sexps.

Your example becomes `(rx "some" (group "regexp"))`

Here are a couple more examples from the commentary section in rx.el, to get an idea of how `rx` works:

This `^;;\\s-*\n\\|^\n`
becomes

```
(rx (or (and line-start ";;" (0+ space) ?\n)
        (and line-start ?\n)))
```

This `[ \t\n]*:\\([^:]+\\|$\\)`
becomes

```
(rx (and (zero-or-more (in " \t\n")) ":"
         (submatch (or line-end (one-or-more (not (any ?:)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @knarf! I was on my phone and didn't want to put in an example that I might get wrong. :-)

Comment: We are actually in the process of moving many scripts that use lots of regex search and replace from perl to elisp because of the `rx` syntax, which makes them easier to maintain.  Imho, for similar cases, [rx syntax](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/shivers/papers/sre.txt) by itself makes elisp a well-worthy substitute for perl python, ruby, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

No it does not have regexp literals, but many find [pcre2el](https://github.com/joddie/pcre2el) to be a helpful alternative.

Specifically using it from elisp like this:

```lisp
(rxt-pcre-to-elisp "(abc|def)\\w+\\d+")
   ;; => "\\(\\(?:abc\\|def\\)\\)[_[:alnum:]]+[[:digit:]]+"
```

Comment: That still requires you to double your backslashes.  You just don't need quite as many for the average regexp.